# How to use NuGet to scaffold to multiple projects in my solution?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nuget, nuget-package, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I have 3 projects in my Solution: MVC, Domain, DAL.

If I have an entity of Tasks with Domain namespace, what is the command line to scaffold the TasksDbContext & TasksRepository in the DAL, TasksArea and TasksController in the MVC?

Thanks in advance.